# Using OpenWRT as DNS server

Tags: networking, router, dns, openwrt

Trying to use OpenWRT as a DNS server for local names. i have set my adsl router up as dhcp server and using the OpenWRT router as the primary dns server with google (8.8.8.8) as the secondary DNS server.

I have added 'router' 192.168.1.1' to the hostnames section of LuCI.

I can ping using cmd '192.168.1.1' and it replies correctly. 
I can browse to 'h t t p://192.168.1.1' using a web browser.
I can ping using cmd 'router' and it resolves correctly. 
I cannot browse to 'h t t p ://router' using a web browser.
I can ping using cmd 'router.lan' and it resolves correctly. 
I cannot browse to 'h t t p://router.lan' using a web browser.

Edit

Using windows 7, with chrome, IE, and firefox.
Using Android with chrome,

The error chrome gives is 
Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

NOT
Error code: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: It might help if you specify which OS and web browser you're using on your client.

Comment: Have you set "Intercept DNS port (UDP 53)"?

Comment: Sounds like you are connected to the adsl router, and you are trying to give your openwrt router a name to resolve? If so, then you need to configure the dhcp option and add the hostname on the adsl router, not on the openwrt.